# Issue with Passenger - Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, passenger

Running in a Linode slice with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

The Apache log has:

Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/2.2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations

caught SIGTERM, shutting down

*** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: The Passenger spawn server script, '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.0/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server', does not exist. Please check whether the 'PassengerRoot' option is specified correctly.

But when we run:
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module. Passenger does not complain.

On restart we get:
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
[Sat Oct 23 23:58:30 2010] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
 ... waiting [Sat Oct 23 23:58:31 2010] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
   ...done.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, something to note above, Apache is looking at Passenger 2.2.7, the failure is coming from Passenger 3.0.0 gem... Dependency conflict?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try (re)installing the native apache module (after installing the gem)

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

I think I had the same problem and it worked after that.

Good luck!

Comment: One note is that I had to say (Y) to overwrite a couple of config files for it to work

Answer (score 8):

I solved this previously using:

```
sudo a2dismod passenger
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Yeah, but that disables the passenger module ... which is fine if you don't need it :-).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your config file is out of whack. Did you run the instructions that follow the install? It looks like it's complaining that you didn't add the PassengerRoot directive to your apache config. The passenger install requires you to add a few lines to your Apache config file manually. On a ubuntu install this is the apache.conf file: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Make sure you add the lines

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.0/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/[username]/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.0
PassengerRuby /home/[username]/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p0/ruby
```

This assumes you are using RVM. If not, the printout and the end of the install will give you the correct path.

Comment: Hi Lucas,Thanks for your post. I did add the three lines in the config file, so I think its not the issue. The problem started when I initiated the setup of passenger-nginx. I already removed nginx, but apache still out of wack. May have to rebuild the whole slice :/