# deployment of application on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

After installing all the necessary configuration, i have facing that problem in the log of Apache server.

passenger-spawn-server', does not exist. Please check whether the 'PassengerRoot' option is specified correctly.

```
Application configuration:

ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2.15
MySQL 2
Apache
Passenger
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link

```
 sudo apt-get install apache2

    http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-apache-with-passenger
```

and i am sure it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the native apache module

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
```

source [Issue with Passenger - Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006666/issue-with-passenger-apache)